# What context is in onPostExecute() of an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I do use lots of AsyncTasks within Activities as private inner classes. One thing that puzzles me since the beginning is what context do I get within onPostExecute()?

If you look at the stripped down example shown below you can use getString() within onPostExecute(). What context is used for that call? The Activity may have changed during doInBackground (e.g. OrientationChange) so it can't be that context.

Currently I patch the Activity context (task.context = this) and use that specific context (context.getString()).

My question: Is it save to use getString() within onPostExecute() of an Inner Class AsyncTask without using the context of the surrounding Activity?

Many thanks in advance.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    /* package */ MyActivity context;

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public MyAsyncTask(final MyActivity context) {
            super();

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(/* ... */) {
            if (context != null) {
                // Currently I do use that
                String s = context.getString(R.string.mytext);
                context.task = null;
            }

            // Would this be save?
            String s2 = getString(R.string.mytext);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute (/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    /* package */ MyAsyncTask  task;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        // ...

        Bundle bundleExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundleExtras != null) {
            task = (MyAsyncTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (task != null) {
                task.context = this;
                // ...
            } else {
                task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
                task.execute();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (task != null) {
            // ...
            task.context = null;
        }

        return task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it save to use getString() within onPostExecute() of an Inner Class AsyncTask without using the context of the surrounding Activity?

No it's not safe. Being an inner class in that activity your `MyAsyncTask` class you'll have a reference to `MyActivity` when it is created. So, if `MyActivity` is killed for any reason (like rotation), in the `onPostExecute` callback you'll end up with `MyAsyncTask` holding a reference of the killed `MyActivity` instance.

Using a reference to the `Activity` it's safer because you update that reference to always point to a valid instance of `MyActivity`. Maybe you'll also want to invalidate the `Activity` directly in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` with `null`  to make sure you don't touch it(if the `MyAsyncTask` reaches the `onPostExecute` until you setup the `MyActivity` again) until you have a valid reference.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. So "getString()" without my own patched "context." in onPostExecute() is simply valid because there's a surrounding Activity around the AsyncTask? So it's more a Java thing than a Android thing. Will take your answer. Thanks.

Comment: "So it's more a Java thing than a Android thing" , yes you're accessing a method of the outer class in the inner class. In `Android` this is to avoid because the outer class(the `Activity`) could be killed independently by the system.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your instance of `MyAsyncTask()` with the `this` pointer in:

```
task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
```

In `onPostExecute` you're accessing the class member `context` initialized with the supplied pointer. Your context is that of the enclosing class i.e. `MyActivity`.

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm doing it currently. My question was: What happens if I use "getString()" instead of the "context.getString()"? Is it save? And what default Context do I get in onPostExecute() when not using my own?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Since it's an enclosed class it will still get the context of the enclosing class i.e. `MyActivity`. In this context, these two are equivalent - `context.getString()` and `getString()`.